# What is the MIN # that looks like a cell number under my actual cell number?

Tags: samsung, settings

When I go to settings, scroll all the way down to "About Phone", and tap on it, all this info pops up. Like MAC address or IP address if you use data. Phone Status and so on. I see my cell number then under it is a MIN # that looks like an actual cell phone number. I called it and a dude named Bill answered. I'm so confused. What is this??

Answer (score 1):

The MIN # is the Mobile Identification Number.  This number is used to uniquely identify your phone within your mobile carriers network and may or may not be the same as your cell phone number, also known the Mobile Directory Number or MDN.  The MIN, just like the MDN, is limited to 10 digits so it appears to be a phone number but is not.